# Pulling Information from Open Weather API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, openweathermap, codepen

I'm writing a web application on [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/lucasfemur/pen/PJoORQ?editors=0011) which takes user location and display the current local weather. I succeeded in pulling the latitude and longitude, but I don't seem to be able to pull the JSON information I need from the API call.

I'm parsing it with AJAX, I believe I've done what the [Official API Documentation](https://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON) asks, but it's not working, the data isn't even displayed on the **console**. I've looked through many answers but I couldn't get it working.

I would like to add the information inside **blockquote**

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    //Return the user's longitude and latitude on page load using HTML5 geolocation API
    window.onload = function () {
    function getCurrentLocation (position) {
        
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      
      console.log(latitude);
      console.log(longitude);

      $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&APPID=b7aaa3a349294d5706002e82df3de1ea&units=metric", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(weather.main.temp);
        $(".city").append(name + " ");
        $(".temperature").append(temp + " ");
        $(".weatherdescription").append(field + " ");
            })
          
        };
    }
   
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCurrentLocation);
    };
```

```html
<h1 class="jumbotron" style="color:white"><em>The Weather Today</em></h1>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class = "row text-center">
  </div>
  <div id="weather" class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12 well message">
      <blockquote id = "raw_json">
        <div class="weatherbox">

      <strong class="city">{CITY NAME HERE}</strong>
    <br/>
      <span class="temperature">{X} °C</span>
    <br/>
      <span class="weatherdescription">{WEATHER DESCRIPTION HERE}</span>
        <br/>

    </div>
    </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your javascript code with the below and it should work.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    //Return the user's longitude and latitude on page load using HTML5 geolocation API
    window.onload = function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCurrentLocation);

    }

}


function getCurrentLocation(position) {

    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log(latitude);
    console.log(longitude);

    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&APPID=b7aaa3a349294d5706002e82df3de1ea&units=metric", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(weather.main.temp);
        $(".city").append(name + " ");
        $(".temperature").append(temp + " ");
        $(".weatherdescription").append(field + " ");
    })

};
```

**CODEPEN:** https://codepen.io/azimjs/pen/KXybpa?editors=0011

Comment: That seems to fix the coordinates problem, thanks! But the API call still empty...

Comment: There were syntax errors. I have updated the codepen. Please mark it as accepted answer if that solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: This did it, thank you! Could you elaborate which syntax errors I've made?

Comment: 1. you did not use the "data" object to fetch the api result. 2. jquery class selector $(".className") returns an array so you are supposed to access it using the array position $(".className")[#]. Thanks!